# WooCommerce get products from "remote" site in widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried installing WooCommerce on my main site. I didn't succeed since my Wordpress theme didn't have WooCommerce support and the layout was way off. So I decided to install WooCommerce on a subdomain in its separate network and with it's own WooCommerce -enabled theme.

Now I would like to have a widget on my main site that displays products that are in Woocommerce on my subdomain. Is this possible? And how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the database from main location , this is not possible so easily. You will have to override the wpdb with new credentials , perform the query , display result and then revert back to original.

Write your own code ,

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb = new wpdb('subdomain-dbuser', 'subdomain-dbpass', 'subdomain-db', 'subdomain-dbserverver');

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

<?php

$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>
<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
  <div class="entry">
     <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
  </div>

  <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

after job is over

assign back to original

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

This code is an idea , you must check on internet for better one , but i believe this should help you.

or install the woo-commerce on main site and customize its template to use remote db.

Regards

Suyash